# SolidColourBrush in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

```
r= byte.Parse(colours[0]); = 255
g= byte.Parse(colours[1]); = 0
b = byte.Parse(colours[2]); = 0
```

I have the RGB values as shown above.When i try to use the variables and retrieve the color I am not getting any color in my HMI but when i pass the same values directly i am able to get the color in my silverlight HMI
    `zoneColour.Color = Color.FromArgb(255,r,g,b);`  - DOES NOT WORK
    `zoneColour.Color = Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0);` -WORKS

Comment: Is this code executed as part of a binding expression? An exception may have occurred without you noticing.
Try to attach a debugger and set a breakpoint on the third line: is it hit? what value is actually stored in r and g?

Answer (score 0):

May this helps you:

```
//r,g and b must be in integer data type
zoneColor.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
```

Another method is [here](http://www.extensionmethod.net/csharp/uint/tosolidcolorbrush).